# Optimal sampling scheme for exponentially distributed data

Tags: statistics, sampling, parameter-estimation

If I have data that I expect to be exponentially distributed (with Gaussian noise), what is the optimal sampling scheme for determining the decay constant? e.g. linearly spaced, logarithmically spaced, etc.

I was told today that it's logarithmically spaced samples, but I don't even know how to go about trying to prove or disprove this.

Comment: Do you mean a model like $Y = \exp(-\alpha X) + \epsilon$?

Comment: @user251257 Yes, that would be fine.